# Update data in source file with random data from another file

Tags: linux

I have data in source file as below (file.txt)

```
N4*WALTER*WHITE~DMG*D8*19630625~N4*JESSI*PINKMAN*15108~
```

Input command: (N4 = segment Identifier, 1= position , ref.txt=reference file)

```
N4*1*ref.txt
```

ref.txt has data as below

```
BILL
LEONARDO
BALE
BRAD
PITT
```

I have below code which displays the data in position x(input)  for N4

```
identifier=N4
position=1
refile=ref.txt

awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" 
   'id { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
         if ($i == id) {
             if (i+pos <= NF)
                 print $(i+pos)
             else
                 print "invalid position"
         }
       }
    ' file.txt

WALTER
JESSI
```

```
identifier=N4
position=2
refile=ref.txt

awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" 
   'id { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
         if ($i == id) {
             if (i+pos <= NF)
                 print $(i+pos)
             else
                 print "invalid position"
         }
       }
    ' file.txt

WHITE
PINKMAN
```

Now how can i integrate ref.txt in above code to update WALTER and JESSI in file.txt with random text located in ref.txt file.

I know shuf command gives random data from ref.txt. but not sure how to integrate this in above awk command.

```
shuf -n -1 ref.txt
```

expected output: file.txt (Position 1 data for N4 segment) to get updated with random text from ref.txt

```
N4*BALE*WHITE~DMG*D8*19630625~N4*PITT*PINKMAN*15108~
```

Comment: What's the purpose in life of `position`?

Comment: @tink: position tells which field to select/print/display for the segment given. example: segment given was N4, so the loop search matches for N4 and print the field in position 1. so it prints WALTER and JESSI

Comment: What do you consider to be `extract`ed?

Comment: I think you need to define your idea of a `field` differently. Would it be feasible to call things separated by `~` records and things in records separated by `*` fields?  Otherwise you'll have a hard time to format your output properly.

Comment: OR you can go one step futher, and have a pre-processing step that converts that data into "record" format, where each line is one record. There was a Q recently on using `RANDOM` inside of `awk` ( which requires newish version of `gawk`), so search for that and apply something like `$2=array[($RANDOM%N)]` to randomly reassign values you've saved to `array[]`. Tryng to make that work with `shuf` will be a process/resource expensive proposition (IMHO). Good luck.

Comment: `Position 1 data for N4 segment` how to iterate over positions and segments in your file? Is the `~` used as a segment separator? and the `*` is used as a position separator? What would be "position 2 for DMG segment? Baht would be position 2 for N4 segment? (JESSI or WALTER or both?) Is the input file always just one long line? Does it always end with `~`? Does it has any newlines in it? Why does the input command not end with `~`?

Comment: AND ... pluse-uno for pretty good beginners Q. Keep posting!

Comment: @KamilCuk:  Yes, ~ used as a segment separator. Yes, * is used as a position separator. Position 2 for DMG segment is 19630625.  I updated original post with position 2 for N4. there are no newlines in input file. yes it always end with ~ as you see in above example.  input command is what i have given, but i am parsing input command into variables in script.

Comment: above code working perfectly to display the field for the given segment and position next to that segment. Only thing i am trying to do is to update the field with random value from ref.txt file.

Comment: So there can be multiple segments with the same  segment identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can do it in bash, but it will be slow with `while read` loop:

```
# recreate the input files
cat <<EOF >file.txt
N4*WALTER*WHITE~DMG*D8*19630625~N4*JESSI*PINKMAN*15108~
EOF
cat <<EOF >input
N4*1*ref.txt
EOF
cat <<EOF >ref.txt
BILL
LEONARDO
BALE
BRAD
PITT
EOF

# read the input
IFS='*' read  -r segment position reference_file <input

{
  # for each line
  while IFS='*' read -r -d'~' -a data; do
    # if the segment id is the segmend
    if [ "${data[0]}" = "$segment" ]; then
        # update the data
        data[$position]=$(shuf -n1 "$reference_file")
    fi
    # and output the data
    ( IFS=*; printf "%s~" "${data[*]}"; )
  done
  # append a newline on the end
  echo
} < file.txt
```

I wanted to try it with `sed` to iterate over segments, but end up preprocessing `sed`s inputs. Below it is, with comments:

```
IFS='*' read  -r segment position reference_file <input

# remove the nelwine from input
# and substitute each `~` with a newline
# so we can nicely process the file in sed
<file.txt tr -d '\n' | tr '~' '\n' >tmp.txt

# count of segments inside input we are interested in
segmentscnt=$(
  grep "^${segment}\*" tmp.txt | wc -l
)

# generate single line with random words from reference_file
# words separated by `*`
# the count of words should that many as many are there
# segments we are interested in the input file
randoms=$(
  while shuf -n1 "$reference_file"; do :; done | 
  head -n"$segmentscnt" |
  tr '\n' '*'
)

sed -n "
  # the first line should be random words from referencefile
  # load it to hold space
  1{
    h
    d
  }
  # if this is our segment
  /^$segment\*/{
    # append random words to our pattern space
    G

    # remember as many fields as the position we want to insert
    # each one word more
    # remember rest of line
    # remember first word from randoms that were inserted from hold space
    # then just substitute the words in proper order
    s/^\(\([^*]*\*\)\{$position\}\)[^*]*\([^\n]*\)\n\([^*]*\)\*.*/\1\4\3/

    # remove the first word from hold space
    x
    s/^\([^*]*\)\*//
    x

  }
  p
# the first input are the random words separated by *
# the words are on a single line
# than the input file
" - <<<"$randoms" tmp.txt |
# then replace newlines with `~`. 
# also append a newline with echo
# as it will be missing
tr '\n' '~'; echo
```